# Phone Number Extracting using RegEx And HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: performance, regex, vb.net, web-scraping

I've written this whole code to extract cell numbers from a website. It is extracting numbers perfectly but very slowly, and it's also hanging my Form while Extracting.

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Extractor

Shared doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

Public Shared Function ScrapLinks(TextBox1 As TextBox, ListBox1 As ListBox, lbllinks As Label)
Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
Try
    doc = hw.Load(TextBox1.Text)
    doc.LoadHtml(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='ad_list']").InnerHtml())

    For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

        Dim hrefValue As String = link.GetAttributeValue("href", String.Empty)

        If hrefValue.Contains("/detail/") Then
            If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(hrefValue) Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(hrefValue)
            End If
        End If
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error " + ex.Message)

End Try
Return Nothing

End Function

Public Shared Function Scrapnums(lstbox As ListBox,lstnum As ListBox)
Try

    Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
    doc = hw.Load(lstbox.SelectedItem)

    Dim data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='det_ad f_left']").InnerText

    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(data, "(\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7}")


    If Not lstnum.Items.Contains(m.Value) Then

        lstnum.Items.Add(m.Value)

    End If

Catch ex As Exception


End Try
Return Nothing

End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Anyone please help me!

Comment: Please be patient. Unlike Stack Overflow, it usually takes hours to days for a response — both because we are a smaller community, and because it takes more time to write a code review answer. Furthermore, you've asked on a weekend, when activity levels are lower.

Comment: @200_success: No-one on SO was willing to help him efficiently scrape phone numbers from a website either, that may well contribute to the silence.

Answer (score 2):

This code has a **major design flaw**.

- Always keep your user interface (UI) separated from your data access layer (DAL).

## ScrapLinks

- Should be named `ScrapeLinks`.
- If a `Function` doesn't return anything, then it should be a `Sub`. In this case, we still want it to be a function.
- No need to have a shared `HtmlDocument` as this is created by the `HtmlWeb`.
- In every iteration where the conditions are met  you add a new value to the `ListBox` item collection. This will result in a **bunch** of windows messages being sent. I guess the most costly is `WM_PAINT`. Scrape the links first, then compare the result with current links. Use the `AddRange` method to insert new items.
- A `Try-Catch` block, whose only purpose is to display an error, should *never* be used outside the UI layer.

```
Public Shared Function ScrapeLinks(url As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)

    If (url Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("url")

    Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
    Dim document As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)

    If (Not document.DocumentNode Is Nothing) Then

        Dim rootNode As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='ad_list']")

        If (Not rootNode Is Nothing) Then

            document.LoadHtml(rootNode.InnerHtml())

            If (Not document.DocumentNode Is Nothing) Then

                Dim childNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

                If (Not childNodes Is Nothing) Then

                    Return (
                        From childNode As HtmlNode
                        In childNodes
                        Let href As String = childNode.GetAttributeValue("href", String.Empty)
                        Where href.Contains("/detail/")
                        Select href
                    )

                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

## Scrapnums

- (Same as above)
- Should be named `ScrapeNumber` as it only returns *one* number.

```
Public Shared Function ScrapeNumber(url As String) As String

    If (url Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("url")

    Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
    Dim document As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)
    Dim root As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='det_ad f_left']")

    If (Not root Is Nothing) Then

        Dim regexMatch As Match = Regex.Match(root.InnerText, "(\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7}")

        If (Not regexMatch Is Nothing) Then
            Return regexMatch.Value
        End If

    End If

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat [Ken Thompson's greatest regret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391001/1157100): spelling `creat()` without an "e".  The functions `ScrapLinks()` and `Scrapnums()` should be called `ScrapeLinks()` and `ScrapeNums()`.  (Even if identifiers in VB.NET are case-insensitive, consistency would be nice.)

In `Scrapnums()`, you swallow the exception.  If anything fails, the user gets no feedback.

It seems odd that you take an `HtmlDocument` (obtained from `hw.Load()`), stringify part of it (using `.InnerHtml()`), then parse it again to obtain another `HtmlDocument`.

That said, there may not be much performance to be gained by optimizing this code, as the execution time will probably be dominated by the HTTP request rather than the parsing.